# Populating ArrayAdapter - type String[]

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Java and Android development and i'm stucked while trying to populate an ArrayAdapter to creating a ListView. The code below works perfectly:

```
        String name[] = {"a","b","c",
            "d","e"};
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.row, R.id.label,
                name));
```

But I simply can't figure out how I should populate `name` with a `for` loop. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why do you want to populate it with a loop? Which values should it have?

Comment: Joachim, I have an SAX XML handler result, and I want to draw it line by line. `for (int i = 0; i < xmlhandler.getName().size(); i++) { }` works fine, but I can't assign the values to name[].

Comment: You need to assign to `name[i]` in that loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter` also has a constructor that takes a `List<String>`, so you can just do

```
List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
for (... ) {
   name.add(.... );
}
this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.row, R.id.label,
                name));
```

Otherwise it just boils down to populating an array with data.